# jQuery - append input into label

Tags: jquery

I have this code that converts select / option into a radio but I do not know how to put the input inside of each label that was created. How do I keep the function of the conversion but instead of adding the label beside the input, put the input inside of the label?

```js
jQuery(".option-list .option").each(function(i, e) {
  if (i != 0) {
    (jQuery("<input type='radio' name='new' />")
      .attr("class", "car-color")
      .attr("value", jQuery(this).val())
      .attr("checked", i == 1)
      .click(function() {
        jQuery(".option-list").val(jQuery(this).val());
      }).add($("<label for=" + this.textContent + ">" + this.textContent + "</label>")))
    .appendTo("#new");

  }
});
jQuery(".option-list").remove();
```

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="option-list">
  <option class="option" value="">Choose Option..</option>
  <option class="option" value="1">Firt</option>
  <option class="option" value="2">Second</option>
  <option class="option" value="3">Third</option>
</select>
<div id="new"></div>
```

Comment: You would `append()` instead of `add()`.  All `add()` does is adds an element to a jQuery result set object.  It doesn't modify the DOM at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke up the steps so it is more readable.  I create the label and then the option, determine if the option should be checked or not, and then add them all to the DOM.

```js
$(".option-list .option").slice(1).each(function(i, e) {
  var $newLabel = $(`<label for="${e.innerText}">${e.innerText}</label>`);
  var $newOption = $(`<input type="radio" name="new" value="${e.value}" class="car-color" id="${e.innerText}">`);
  
  if (!i) $newOption.prop('checked', true);
  
  $newLabel.append($newOption);
  $('#new').append($newLabel);
});

$(".option-list").remove();
```

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="option-list">
  <option class="option" value="">Choose Option..</option>
  <option class="option" value="1">First</option>
  <option class="option" value="2">Second</option>
  <option class="option" value="3">Third</option>
</select>
<div id="new"></div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan hah, I completely mind blanked on that, since the inputs were nested in the labels, I usually leave off ids.  But the OP had the `for=""` tag so, meh, added it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the label first

But why the onclick to set a value if you remove the select?

Also you forgot ID

```js
const $div = $("#new")
$div.on("click", "[name=new]", function() {
  $(".option-list").val(this.value)
}); // why this if you remove the select???
$(".option-list .option:gt(0)").each(function(i, e) {
  $div.append(
    $("<label/>", {
      for: this.text,
      text: this.text
    }).append(
      $("<input/>", {
        "id": this.text,
        "type": "radio",
        "name": "new",
        "class": "car-color",
        "value": this.value,
        "checked": i===0
      })
    ))
});
// $(".option-list").remove();
```

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="option-list">
  <option class="option" selected value="">Choose Option..</option>
  <option class="option" value="1">First</option>
  <option class="option" value="2">Second</option>
  <option class="option" value="3">Third</option>
</select>
<div id="new"></div>
```